# Encoding a PDF using matrix multiplication

Tags: pdf, cryptography, mathematica

I need to encode a patent application in a PDF file using matrix multiplication on Mathematica so I can save it on a cloud storage service so my partner can download the encoded file in Asia and decode it using inverse matrix multiplication.

The challenge is we do not want to use any commercially available software to achieve this objective.

Can anyone help us?

Thanks!

Joe

Comment: Convert the file to a matrix, do the multiplication and you're done? What is givign you trouble?

Comment: I am embarrassed to say that despite using Mathematica for nearly ten years, I cannot find how to convert a file into a matrix. Thank you in advance for your help. Joe

Comment: If I'm not mistaken [this](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Files.html) would be the help for Mathematica, isn't it? Seems to quite straight forward to read a file. You probably could do something like ReadByteArray and work with that. I don't know much about Mathematica so I don't know how you'd do a matrix multiplication on that.